# Console.WriteLine does not work inside a C# Eventhandler

Tags: c#, console-application

```
class Program
{
    FileSystemWatcher _watchFolder;
    string sPath = @"D:\TestMonitor";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(p.startActivityMonitoring));
        t.Start();
    }


    private void startActivityMonitoring()
    {
        _watchFolder = new FileSystemWatcher();
        _watchFolder.Path = Convert.ToString(sPath);
        _watchFolder.NotifyFilter = System.IO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        _watchFolder.NotifyFilter =
        _watchFolder.NotifyFilter | System.IO.NotifyFilters.FileName;
        _watchFolder.NotifyFilter =
        _watchFolder.NotifyFilter | System.IO.NotifyFilters.Attributes;
        _watchFolder.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(eventRaised);
        _watchFolder.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(eventRaised);
        _watchFolder.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(eventRaised);
        _watchFolder.Renamed += new System.IO.RenamedEventHandler(eventRaised);
        _watchFolder.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }



    private void eventRaised(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.ChangeType)
        {
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Changed:
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File {0} has been modified\r\n", e.FullPath));

                break;
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Created:
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File {0} has been created\r\n", e.FullPath));

                break;
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted:
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File {0} has been deleted\r\n", e.FullPath));

                break;
            default: // Another action
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

A simple program using FileSystemWatcher to poll for changes inside a directory when i try to log the changes using Console.WriteLine it does not work though.

Not sure what is causing this issue since Console.WriteLine works well inside any thread

Comment: Are you sure that the event is fired and that the `Console.WriteLine` method is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is exiting right after it starts the thread. You need to keep the program running. 
One simple way would to be include a Console.ReadLine to stop the program from exiting.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(p.startActivityMonitoring));
        t.Start();
        Console.Writeline("Press enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry i missed Console.WriteLine() when i copied the code :(.The actual issue is though i am able to see events raised Console.WriteLine does not log to the console

Comment: You are missing the Console.ReadLine, which will make the program wait?